# Visual Basic / Studio designer will not open

Tags: vb.net, designer, basic

Every time I save a project and close the program, when I try to come back it just opens up http://puu.sh/8Jrow.png It is quite annoying, I have tried clicking both: "Designer.vb AND the .vb" http://puu.sh/8JrtS.png Each of them do not open the designer, when I go to view, there is no option to view the Designer. Any solutions?

Comment: does right click view designer work?

Comment: On the windows explorer? or where would that be located?

Comment: Well, I did find the **rightclick view designer** just not what I'm looking for I don't think. the thing I'm looking for is the designer that opens where I can edit the form, buttons, open toolbar, ect.

Comment: Which version of Studio are you using?

Comment: Actually, I feel rather silly. I wasn't clicking save all..